# Understanding jQuery slider functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  $("#text_slider div:gt(0)").hide();

 setInterval(function() { 
$("#text_slider div:first")
  .fadeOut(500).next().fadeIn(500).end().appendTo("#text_slider");

},5000);
```

My html code is

```
<body>
<div id="text_slider">
<div><p>First Text</p></div>
<div><p>Second Text</p></div>
<div><p>Third Text</p></div>
</div>
<script src="C:\Users\bonny\Documents\samples sites\jquery\jquery.js">      </script>
 <script src="1.js"></script>
 </body>
```

My css

```
 #text_slider{
width:600px;
height:300px;
margin:100px auto;
box-shadow:0 0 5px 5px #000;
}
#text_slider div {
position:absolute;

}
 #text_slider p{
margin:20px;
font-size:30px;

 }
```

I am building a text slider using jquery and saw the above jquery code being successfully used in a tutorial but I am having difficulty in understanding how it works.Here's what I know:
The first statement hides all the text(all 3 sub-divs) to prevent them from stacking on top of each other at the  beginning.
At first the fadeOut function moves on "first text" div and then moves to its sibling(I think ?) the "Second Text " div , and "second text" div fades in 500ms .Then the end() redirects the property to the container div.( But I am lost as to how the rest of the  program works after that . What does Append do in the above code.

Please correct me if my explanation above is wrong somewhere.I am still new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("#text_slider div:gt(0)").hide();` - Hides all div's that are children of the "text_slider" div, except for the first.  That the `:gt(0)` part.

`setInterval(function, 5000)` says run the code inside the function every 5 seconds.

`$("#text_slider div:first")` Finds the first div that is a child of "text_slider"

`.fadeOut(500)` Fades it out in 1/2 second.

`.next()` moves to the next sibling.

`.fadeIn(500)` fades in that sibling in 1/2 second

`.end()` goes back to the originally selected element in this chain, or the first child div.

`.appendTo("#text_slider");` appends the first child div to the end, basically re-ordering it and making it the last child. The others move up in order.

Comment: Once appendTo() has been used , does "Second text" become first child of parent div since "First text" is added to the end?

Comment: Does it move to next sibling with next() only when current div has faded in? Sorry if its a noob question.

Comment: Once appendTo is used, the first div is moved to the end and the other two move up, so the new order would be second, third, first.  This is what allows the same code to rotate through all the divs.  The next time the code runs, "Second text" would be the new first child and would fade out.  I believe the next() wouldn't be called until after the first div is faded out, but It could also just be queueing up the animations.  Either way the effect is the same, the second child isn't faded in until after the first div fades out.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#text_slider div:gt(0)").hide();
```

This line of code hides all div's found inside #text_slider except for the first div. Check the reference to the :gt() selector here : https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

```
   setInterval(function() {
     $("#text_slider div:first")
       .fadeOut(500).next().fadeIn(500).end().appendTo("#text_slider");
   }, 5000);
```

Once the other divs are hidden, the code displays just the first div (using the :first selector - https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and this setInterval function then takes over to be executed at every 5 second intervals.
The first div inside the #text_slider is found and faded out , then using the next() function, the following div which was earlier hidden is then found and fadedIn and finally, the div that has been faded out is appended to the #text_slider div thus reordering the three divs inside the text_slider div. So that at all times the #text_slider has html containing all three child divs.

---

Check this working fiddle here : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jairajdesai/kramyx1v/)